# Como alinhar imagens de diferentes tamanhos em layout responsivo?

Tags: html, css

Não estou sabendo lidar com o seguinte problema.

Estava tentando trabalhar com o `<li class="filme">`, com seu tamanho responsivo, porém como cada imagem tem um tamanho variável. Quando chega em determinado tamanho as imagens começam a quebrar o layout. Se defino tamanho as imagens, minha `<li class="filme">` para começar a crescer mais do que a imagem. Pois, a `<li>` está em % e a imagem em pixel. Se eu defino o `width` da li como auto(para ocupar o tamanho da imagem) meu layout na medida que vai crescendo fica um espaço em branco no layout.

**HTML:**

```
<main class="principal">
    <section class="section-filmes">
        <ul id="lista-filmes" class="lista-filmes">
            <!-- Lista de filmes aqui..-->
            <li class="filme"> <img src="img-filme"> </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</main>
```

**CSS:**

```
img{ max-width 100% }
.lista-filmes::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.lista-filmes .filme{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

Obs: As imagens dos filmes são tamanhos variáveis, exemplo 400x600 300x450 800x900 e etc.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma solução pra deixar as imagens responsivas, sem quebrar o layout.

A idéia é que no final fique assim: [clique aqui para ver](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/imagens-animes-jpg)

Porem responsiva.

Answer (score 0):

O `max-width: 100%` está correto, pois assim as imagens irão se autoajustar dentro da `li` até sua largura máxima ou a largura da `li`, o que for menor.

Como as larguras das imagens são variáveis, o que resta a fazer é centralizar as imagens, e você pode fazer isso adicionando:

```
.lista-filmes .filme img{
   max-width: 100%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
.lista-filmes .filme img{
   max-width: 100%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.lista-filmes::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.lista-filmes .filme{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<main class="principal">
    <section class="section-filmes">
        <ul id="lista-filmes" class="lista-filmes">
            // Lista de filmes aqui..
            <li class="filme"> <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg"> </li>
            <li class="filme"> <img src="https://a.edim.co/images_v2/opengraph/og_logo.png"> </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</main>
```

Uma outra solução seria colocar um `span` e inserir a imagem como background. Como as imagens variam de tamanho, poderá haver cortes, mas as imagens ficarão centralizadas:

```css
.lista-filmes::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.lista-filmes .filme{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: .5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#lista-filmes .filme span{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main class="principal">
    <section class="section-filmes">
        <ul id="lista-filmes" class="lista-filmes">
            <li class="filme">
               <span style="background-image: url(https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg);"></span>
               texto texto
            </li>
            <li class="filme">
               <span style="background-image: url(https://a.edim.co/images_v2/opengraph/og_logo.png);"></span>
               texto texto
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: a ideia é que no final fique assim: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/imagens-animes-jpg,
Eu pensei em alinha a imagem no centro também, mas as li's iriam crescer, não dando o "efeito" que eu quero :s

Comment: então as imagens teriam um width e height definidos exemplo: width: 150px; height: 200px;, porem o problema passaria a ser a li, que teria largura e altura variavel, e caso não tenha  ela não conseguiria acompanhar o layout

Comment: não, o que eu quis dizer foi que, eu receberia imagens de tamanhos variaveis e no css definiria um tamanho para elas entendeu?

Comment: eu utilizaria o object-fit: cover; para ajustar a imagem

Comment: Não eu nem estudei sobre, só fui pesquisar como deixar as imagens na mesma proporção sem perder a qualidade, estou vendo que oq eu quero parece mais complexo do que eu penso ser :S

Comment: Sua intenção é deixar todas as imagens do mesmo tamanho e as LIs tb?

Comment: Sim, essa era a minha intenção, porem ao longo do "desenvolvimento", vi que de qualquer maneira que eu fizesse não atingia meu objetivo, ai vim recorrer ao stack :s

Comment: Vc terá que usar javascript, porque as LIs podem variar de altura dependendo do texto... na imagem de exemplo que vc mandou isso não ocorre porque o texto é cortado quando é mt longo, fazendo com que ocupe apenas uma linha.

Comment: No caso das imagens, é inevitável o corte, porque as imagens tem tamanho variáveis.

Comment: A sim, isso eu já ajustei, ficou pendente mesmo as imagens, que pelo que parece, minha ideia só seria possível se o as imagens tivessem tamanho padrão

Comment: Sim, senão elas terão cortes nas bordas.

Comment: Sim sim, como não sou nenhum expert em css, recorri ao stack pra saber se tem alguma solução pra esse caso, mas obrigado pela sua atenção e explicação dvd ^^ (mais uma vez)